# Filtering a dataframe column with another column in a separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe table (table_1) that contains 3 cloumns:

| Iteam ID | Date / time | Date / time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-03-21 - 00:27:00 | 2022-03-21 - 00:28:00 |
| 99 | 2022-03-21 - 00:25:00 | 2022-03-21 - 00:26:00 |
| 34 | 2022-03-21 - 00:22:00 | 2022-03-21 - 00:23:00 |
| 28 | 2022-03-21 - 00:21:00 | 2022-03-21 - 00:23:00 |

I want to be able to filter the column Iteam Id with the data in another data-frame column (table_2).

| Iteam Id |
| --- |
| 12 |
| 34 |
| 28 |

So the output would be:

| Iteam ID | Date / time | Date / time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-03-21 - 00:27:00 | 2022-03-21 - 00:28:00 |
| 34 | 2022-03-21 - 00:22:00 | 2022-03-21 - 00:23:00 |
| 28 | 2022-03-21 - 00:21:00 | 2022-03-21 - 00:23:00 |

I have tryed creating a new dataframe using:

```
    new_df = table_1[table_1['Iteam ID'].isin(table_2)
```

But it is returning an empty dataframe, any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct column instead of the whole dataframe:

```
new_df = table_1[table_1['Iteam ID'].isin(table_2['Iteam ID'].values)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge (inner join) them :

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='Iteam Id')
```